# OpenCV 3: List of available FeatureDetector::create() and DescriptorExtractor::create() options?

Tags: c++, opencv

**edit:** I was looking at the wrong OpenCV2 code example, there is no `FeatureDetector::create` in OpenCV3 - this was confusing me.

---

Hey new to OpenCV and learning by example by pulling apart other peoples C++ code.

I would like to try all available options for:

```
detector = FeatureDetector::create(str_detector);
descriptor = DescriptorExtractor::create(str_descriptor);
```

currently str_detector is `FAST` and str_descriptor is `BRISK`

I am having trouble finding what available Detectors and Descriptors are available to me.

Is there a way to output a list of all currently available options?

(I have just built the latest opencv + opencv-contrib from github on a fresh linux install)

I have found a list of 3rd party files here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src - I think these are 3rd Descriptors and Detectors because those words are mentioned in some of the files. However it would be nice to have a full list of currently compiled/available options to play with.

Thanks!

---

Trying to find the answer myself, edits as I go:

1. Found `typedef Feature2D FeatureDetector` and `typedef Feature2D DescriptorExtractor` in `modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp`
2. Digging for `Feature2D` now...
3. I'm so confused, my C++ is failing me, there is no `create` in https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/feature2d.cpp
4. ok so just looking through the code ( https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp )

   - BRISK
   - ORB
   - MSER
   - FastFeatureDetector / FAST
   - AgastFeatureDetector / AGAST
   - GFTTDetector
   - SimpleBlobDetector
   - KAZE / AKAZE
5. and from the contrib code ( https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/include/opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp )

   - FREAK
   - StarDetector
   - BriefDescriptorExtractor
   - LUCID
   - LATCH
   - DAISY
   - MSDDetector
6. and from nonfree contrib code ( https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/include/opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp )

   - SIFT
   - SURF
7. Still unsure which of the above can/should be used for FeatureDetector or DescriptorExtractor

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have also the OpenCV documentation to have a list of OpenCV features:

- [OpenCV 3.1 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d51/group__features2d__main.html)
- [OpenCV 3.1 contrib documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/db4/group__xfeatures2d.html)

What I do to know if the feature is available only in keypoints detection or descriptor extraction or both is to read the corresponding paper linked in the documentation. It allows also to have a brief description of the features (for example if it is a binary descriptor, main advantages, etc.)

Other solution is to test each feature:

- if the call to `detect()` is ok (no exception thrown) ==> feature detection
- if the call to `compute()` is ok ==> feature extraction
- if the call to `detectAndCompute()` is ok ==> both
- or looking directly into the source code.

Maybe a more optimal solution exists...

Anyway, from my knowledge (feel free to correct me if I am wrong):

- BRISK: detector + descriptor
- ORB: detector + descriptor
- MSER: detector
- FAST: detector
- AGAST: detector
- GFFT: detector
- SimpleBlobDetector: detector
- KAZE: detector + descriptor
- AKAZE: detector + descriptor
- FREAK: descriptor
- StarDetector: detector
- BriefDescriptorExtractor: descriptor
- LUCID: descriptor
- LATCH: descriptor
- DAISY: descriptor
- MSDDetector: detector
- SIFT: detector + descriptor
- SURF: detector + descriptor

Also with OpenCV 3.1, the code is:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::Feature2D> kaze = cv::KAZE::create(); 
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> kpts; 
cv::Mat descriptors; 
kaze->detect(matImg, kpts); 
kaze->compute(matImg, kpts, descriptors); 
kaze->detectAndCompute(matImg, cv::noArray(), kpts, descriptors);

cv::Ptr<cv::Feature2D> daisy = cv::xfeatures2d::DAISY::create(); //Contrib
```

To know which norm type to use:

```
  std::cout << "AKAZE: " << akaze->descriptorType() << " ; CV_8U=" << CV_8U << std::endl;
  std::cout << "AKAZE: " << akaze->defaultNorm() << " ; NORM_HAMMING=" << cv::NORM_HAMMING << std::endl;
```

Finally, why

> [No more features2d::create?](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4009)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing that knowledge! :) 

I just realised there is a `#if CV_MAJOR_VERSION > 2` in this code, and it is using the newer `detector = cv::FastFeatureDetector::create();` instead of the old `detector = FeatureDetector::create(str_detector);`. That makes much more sense and matches up with the documentation/source code. Cheers