# Trying to get OpenCV to work in Java, sample code to stitch 2 photos together

Tags: java, opencv, opencv-stitching

I'm trying to use OpenCV in Java.  I want to stitch 2 photos together.  OpenCV is a C++ library and it has a Java wrapper.

1. I downloaded OpenCV Java with the pre-build Windows .dll's from the official site:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.4.1/opencv-3.4.1-vc14_vc15.exe/download
2. I'm using IntelliJ 2016.1.4
3. I set up my project and pointed it to the relevant .jar
4. I found code like you see below on the web.
5. It didn't work out of the box so I fixed a couple of things, e.g.:
       private static final int CV_RANSAC = 8; // This is just a guess!
6. I ran it. It fails with the error:  "error: (-5) Specified descriptor extractor type is not supported"  on the line:              fe = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SURF);  I
7. I tried a bunch of alternative algoriths (ORB, SIFT, BRIEF) and got the same error.

I'd like to get this code working.  Ideally I'd get working code which is not using a bunch of deprecated functions...the functions are deprecated but there's no comment saying what I should use instead...that always annoys me.

(More generally I'd like any working Java sample code which can stitch together photos to form a panorama.)

Can anyone help?

```
import org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d;
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorExtractor;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher;
import org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector;
import org.opencv.features2d.Features2d;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread;
import static org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imwrite;


public class ImageStitching {

    static Mat image1;
    static Mat image2;

    static FeatureDetector fd;
    static DescriptorExtractor fe;
    static DescriptorMatcher fm;


    // Compulsory
    static{
        try {
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        }
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find \"" + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME + ".dll .\n"
                    +"You need to add something like this to the run configuration \"VM options\":\n"
                    +"-Djava.library.path=C:\\OpenCvPreBuilt\\opencv\\build\\java\\x64");
        }
    }


    public static void go()
    {
        //new CvException("hello");
        fd = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.BRISK);
        fe = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SURF);
        fm = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);

        //images
        image1 = imread("A.jpg");
        image2 = imread("B.jpg");

        //structures for the keypoints from the 2 images
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

        //structures for the computed descriptors
        Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
        Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();

        //structure for the matches
        MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();

        //getting the keypoints
        fd.detect(image1, keypoints1);
        fd.detect(image1, keypoints2);

        //getting the descriptors from the keypoints
        fe.compute(image1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
        fe.compute(image2,keypoints2,descriptors2);

        //getting the matches the 2 sets of descriptors
        fm.match(descriptors2,descriptors1, matches);

        //turn the matches to a list
        List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();

        Double maxDist = 0.0; //keep track of max distance from the matches
        Double minDist = 100.0; //keep track of min distance from the matches

        //calculate max & min distances between keypoints
        for(int i=0; i<keypoints1.rows();i++){
            Double dist = (double) matchesList.get(i).distance;
            if (dist<minDist) minDist = dist;
            if(dist>maxDist) maxDist=dist;
        }

        System.out.println("max dist: " + maxDist );
        System.out.println("min dist: " + minDist);

        //structure for the good matches
        LinkedList<DMatch> goodMatches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();

        //use only the good matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist)
        for(int i=0;i<descriptors1.rows();i++){
            if(matchesList.get(i).distance<3*minDist){
                goodMatches.addLast(matchesList.get(i));
            }
        }

        //structures to hold points of the good matches (coordinates)
        LinkedList<Point> objList = new LinkedList<Point>(); // image1
        LinkedList<Point> sceneList = new LinkedList<Point>(); //image 2

        List<KeyPoint> keypoints_objectList = keypoints1.toList();
        List<KeyPoint> keypoints_sceneList = keypoints2.toList();

        //putting the points of the good matches into above structures
        for(int i = 0; i<goodMatches.size(); i++){
            objList.addLast(keypoints_objectList.get(goodMatches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
            sceneList.addLast(keypoints_sceneList.get(goodMatches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
        }

        System.out.println("\nNum. of good matches" +goodMatches.size());

        MatOfDMatch gm = new MatOfDMatch();
        gm.fromList(goodMatches);

        //converting the points into the appropriate data structure
        MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
        obj.fromList(objList);

        MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f();
        scene.fromList(sceneList);

        //finding the homography matrix
        Mat H = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC, 3);

        //LinkedList<Point> cornerList = new LinkedList<Point>();
        Mat obj_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);
        Mat scene_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);

        obj_corners.put(0,0, new double[]{0,0});
        obj_corners.put(0,0, new double[]{image1.cols(),0});
        obj_corners.put(0,0,new double[]{image1.cols(),image1.rows()});
        obj_corners.put(0,0,new double[]{0,image1.rows()});

        Core.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

        //structure to hold the result of the homography matrix
        Mat result = new Mat();

        //size of the new image - i.e. image 1 + image 2
        Size s = new Size(image1.cols()+image2.cols(),image1.rows());

        //using the homography matrix to warp the two images
        Imgproc.warpPerspective(image1, result, H, s);
        int i = image1.cols();
        Mat m = new Mat(result,new Rect(i,0,image2.cols(), image2.rows()));

        image2.copyTo(m);

        Mat img_mat = new Mat();

        Features2d.drawMatches(image1, keypoints1, image2, keypoints2, gm, img_mat, new Scalar(254,0,0),new Scalar(254,0,0) , new MatOfByte(), 2);

        //creating the output file
        boolean imageStitched = imwrite("imageStitched.jpg",result);
        boolean imageMatched = imwrite("imageMatched.jpg",img_mat);
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        go();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, lets have another try.
I will skip all the initialising stuff, since you seem to have been successfull in loading the library.

For my environment:

- I use OpenCV on android with the stock Java wrapper provided by the download you linked yourself.
- OpenCV is used in version 3.4.1
- I develop in Android Studio 3.1.3

I put comments in the code whereever I could and added the sources (stackoverflow or other) to show where I found the code.

At this point many thanks for these people for helping me piece together something which actually works.

The following method is what stitches two images together 
(extracted from a AsyncTask since it takes a lot of time):

```
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap...arg0) {

        // Base code extracted from: http://privateblog.info/sozdanie-panoramy-s-pomoshhyu-opencv-i-java/
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691050/opencv-3-list-of-available-featuredetectorcreate-and-descriptorextractorc
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681389/how-to-multiply-2-matrices-in-java-and-then-use-the-result-as-transformation-mat
        // Measuring the duration
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        // Abort if we got not the right amount of images...
        // Stitching more than two images is not supported.
        if (arg0.length != 2) {
            return null;
        }

        // Get the two images from the given arguments
        Bitmap bitmap1 = arg0[0];
        Bitmap bitmap2 = arg0[1];

        // If something is wrong, abort...
        if (bitmap1 == null || bitmap2 == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Convert the two bitmaps to OpenCV mats...
        Mat img1 = new Mat();
        Mat img2 = new Mat();

        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap1, img1);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap2, img2);

        // ...then create greyscale versions
        Mat gray_image1 = new Mat();
        Mat gray_image2 = new Mat();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, gray_image1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, gray_image2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

        // At this point search for keypoints in both images and compute the matches
        MatOfKeyPoint keyPoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        MatOfKeyPoint keyPoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

        Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
        Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();

        // Since FeatureDetector and Descriptor extractor are marked deprecated and
        // crash whatever value they get, use this construct for detecting and computing...
        // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691050/opencv-3-list-of-available-featuredetectorcreate-and-descriptorextractorc
        KAZE kaze = KAZE.create();
        kaze.detect(gray_image1, keyPoints1);
        kaze.detect(gray_image2, keyPoints2);
        kaze.compute(gray_image1, keyPoints1, descriptors1);
        kaze.compute(gray_image2, keyPoints2, descriptors2);

        MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();

        DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.FLANNBASED);
        matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

        // Calculate min and max distance between the keypoints in the two images.
        double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;
        List<DMatch> listMatches = matches.toList();

        for( int i = 0; i < listMatches.size(); i++ ) {
            double dist = listMatches.get(i).distance;
            if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
            if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
        }

        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Min: " + min_dist);
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Max: " + max_dist);

        // Reduce the list of matching keypoints to a list of good matches...
        LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
        MatOfDMatch goodMatches = new MatOfDMatch();
        for(int i = 0; i < listMatches.size(); i++) {
            if(listMatches.get(i).distance < 2*min_dist) {
                good_matches.addLast(listMatches.get(i));
            }
        }

        goodMatches.fromList(good_matches);
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Number of matches: " + listMatches.size());
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Number of good matches: " + good_matches.size());

        // Calculate the homograohy between the two images...
        LinkedList<Point> imgPoints1List = new LinkedList<Point>();
        LinkedList<Point> imgPoints2List = new LinkedList<Point>();
        List<KeyPoint> keypoints1List = keyPoints1.toList();
        List<KeyPoint> keypoints2List = keyPoints2.toList();

        for(int i = 0; i<good_matches.size(); i++) {
            imgPoints1List.addLast(keypoints1List.get(good_matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
            imgPoints2List.addLast(keypoints2List.get(good_matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
        }

        MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
        obj.fromList(imgPoints1List);
        MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f();
        scene.fromList(imgPoints2List);

        Mat H = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene, Calib3d.RANSAC,3);

        int imageWidth = img2.cols();
        int imageHeight = img2.rows();

        // To avoid missing some of the possible stitching scenarios, we offset the homography to the middle of a mat which has three time the size of one of the pictures.
        // Extracted from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618044/stitching-2-images-opencv
        Mat Offset = new Mat(3, 3, H.type());
        Offset.put(0,0, new double[]{1});
        Offset.put(0,1, new double[]{0});
        Offset.put(0,2, new double[]{imageWidth});
        Offset.put(1,0, new double[]{0});
        Offset.put(1,1, new double[]{1});
        Offset.put(1,2, new double[]{imageHeight});
        Offset.put(2,0, new double[]{0});
        Offset.put(2,1, new double[]{0});
        Offset.put(2,2, new double[]{1});

        // Multiply the homography mat with the offset.
        Core.gemm(Offset, H, 1, new Mat(), 0, H);

        Mat obj_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);
        Mat scene_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);

        obj_corners.put(0,0, new double[]{0,0});
        obj_corners.put(0,0, new double[]{imageWidth,0});
        obj_corners.put(0,0,new double[]{imageWidth,imageHeight});
        obj_corners.put(0,0,new double[]{0,imageHeight});

        Core.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

        // The resulting mat will be three times the size (width and height) of one of the source images. (We assume, that both images have the same size.
        Size s = new Size(imageWidth *3,imageHeight*3);
        Mat img_matches = new Mat(new Size(img1.cols()+img2.cols(),img1.rows()), CvType.CV_32FC2);

        // Perform the perspective warp of img1 with the given homography and place it on the large result mat.
        Imgproc.warpPerspective(img1, img_matches, H, s);

        // Create another mat which is used to hold the second image and place it in the middle of the large sized result mat.
        int m_xPos = (int)(img_matches.size().width/2 - img2.size().width/2);
        int m_yPos = (int)(img_matches.size().height/2 - img2.size().height/2);
        Mat m = new Mat(img_matches,new Rect(m_xPos, m_yPos, img2.cols(), img2.rows()));

        // Copy img2 to the mat in the middle of the large result mat
        img2.copyTo(m);

        // Some debug logging... and some duration logging following...
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Size of img2: width=" + img2.size().width + "height=" + img2.size().height);
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Size of m: width=" + m.size().width + "height=" + m.size().height);
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Size of img_matches: width=" + img_matches.size().width + "height=" + img_matches.size().height);

        long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime / 1000000; // Milliseconds (1:1000000)
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Stitching 2 images took " + elapsedTime + "ms");
        //loadedImagesText.append("Stitching 2 images took " + elapsedTime + "ms\n");

        // The resulting mat is way to big. It holds a lot of empty "transparent" space.
        // We will not crop the image, so that only the "region of interest" remains.
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int stepping = 6;

        Rect imageBoundingBox3 = findImageBoundingBox2(img_matches, stepping, true);

        elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime / 1000000; // Milliseconds (1:1000000)
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Resulting rect has tl(x=" + imageBoundingBox3.tl().x + ", y=" + imageBoundingBox3.tl().y +") and br(x=" + imageBoundingBox3.br().x + ", y=" + imageBoundingBox3.br().y +") with stepping="+stepping+" and auto-correct=true\n");
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Cropping stitched image (v2.1) took " + elapsedTime + "ms");

        //loadedImagesText.append("Resulting rect has tl(x=" + imageBoundingBox3.tl().x + ", y=" + imageBoundingBox3.tl().y +") and br(x=" + imageBoundingBox3.br().x + ", y=" + imageBoundingBox3.br().y +") with stepping="+stepping+" and auto-correct=true\n");
        //loadedImagesText.append("Cropping stitched image (v2.1) took " + elapsedTime + "ms\n");

        // Extract the calculated region of interest from the result mat.
        Mat regionOfInterest = img_matches.submat(imageBoundingBox3);

        // Convert the end result to a bitmap and we are done!
        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(regionOfInterest.cols(),  regionOfInterest.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(regionOfInterest, resultBitmap);

        return resultBitmap;
    }
```

As for a final comment:

OpenCV itself has a high level class called "stitcher".
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html

This class would do all the manual labour my code does AND also allow the stitching of more than two images.
But it seems this class is not yet included in the stock java wrapper.

Hope I could help and this time provide a propper answer.

Comment: Hi Zoe. I know, that I am not providing an answer here. I was merely asking the author whether he is still interested in a possible answer after his question was inactive for 3 months. I would have put this as a simple comment to his question... but since being fairly new, I was not able to do that. If you can, please convert my question to a comment.

Comment: @Moritz: Ok. That's somewhat crude, but a honest answer. Thank you for that. I will revise my post.

Comment: Is there anyway to optimize this if you know the images are taken in a clockwise rotation?  For example only looking in the right half and left half of the given images?  also is there a faster way to find the bounding box just brute forcing it takes forever even if you jump 5 or 6 pixels each iteration.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you found how to do it?